# iPhoneの写真アプリ内の写真を自作アプリ内に自動で同期することはできますか？

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, iphone

iPhoneの写真アプリ内の写真を自作アプリ内に自動で同期することはできますか？

例えば写真アプリ内につくった特定のアルバムの写真だけを同期するということをしたいのですが。

Comment: どういったアプリか不明なので解答がつけられないです。今のままだと、アプリがアクティブ（起動した）の際に取り込めばいいのでは？と思います。またバックグラウンド処理は(レビュワーが納得できる)正当な理由がないとリジェクトくらいます。バッテリー消費がユーザの意図しないところで増えるからですね。[`バックグラウンドで処理することにより全体的な使い勝手が向上するのでなければ、回避できないか検討してください。`](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。アプリ起動時にアルバムと同期する形で良いです。そのような方法があるのですね？メソッドとか。

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit

Comment: そういうのがあるんですね。ありがとうございます！